# Animation objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

So i intend to make a view that is pretty much a line with the anchor point at it's base to wobble from right to left and play a sound when it reaches the max angle. (Implementation of a metronome arm)

my methods are :

```
-(void)goForward :(UIView*)view{

CGAffineTransform rightWobble = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(120));

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

    view.transform=rightWobble;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"go back  duration : %f",duration);

    if (isWobbling) {
        [self goBack:view];
        [self performSelector:@selector(playMetronomeSound) withObject:nil afterDelay:duration];  
    }
    else if (!isWobbling){
            [self stopWobbling];
            [self performSelector:@selector(stopMetronomeSound) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    }

}];  }
```

and

```
-(void)goBack :(UIView*)view{


CGAffineTransform leftWobble = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(RADIANS(60));

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{

    view.transform = leftWobble;

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    NSLog(@"go forward  duration: %f",duration);

    if (isWobbling) {
        [self goForward:view];
        [self performSelector:@selector(playMetronomeSound) withObject:nil afterDelay:duration];
        }
    else if (!isWobbling){
        [self stopWobbling];
        [self performSelector:@selector(stopMetronomeSound) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}];  }
```

with

```
-(void) stopWobbling{

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    metronomeSlider.transform = vertical;
    [self stopMetronomeSound];
}]; }
```

and

```
-(void) playMetronomeSound{

        alSourcePlay(mySoundSource);
}

-(void) stopMetronomeSound{

        alSourceStop(mySoundSource);
}
```

The duration variable determines the duration of the animation. 
The animation happens when i hit a play button that looks like this:

```
-(void)playButtonAction {
if (_metronomeIsAnimatingAndPLaying == NO)
{
    [self goForward:metronomeSlider];

    [_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stop"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self performSelector:@selector(playMetronomeSound) withObject:nil afterDelay:duration];

    _metronomeIsAnimatingAndPLaying = YES;
    isWobbling = YES;

    NSLog(@"DURATION IS : %f",duration);

}

else if (_metronomeIsAnimatingAndPLaying == YES)
{
    [_playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self stopWobbling];

    _metronomeIsAnimatingAndPLaying = NO;
    isWobbling = NO;
}   }
```

My problem is whenever i hit the play / stop button to make the animation stop and my view to come back to a 90 degrees angle, it happens but it plays an extra tick sound that is not meant to be played.

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Thankx in advance

Update Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: please share a screen shot for better understanding of your issue.

Comment: what sound frame work are you using?

Comment: @MaKo CoreAudio Framework

Comment: Maybe you should try to put your stopMetronomSound method call outside animations block. Like this -(void) stopWobbling{
[self stopMetronomeSound];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    metronomeSlider.transform = vertical;
}]; }

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is happening:

1. You call [self stopWobbling]
2. stopWobbling calls animateWithDuration on the transform
3. This will cause the completion block of the running animation to be called (with finished = NO)
4. In that block isWobbling is still true (since you haven't set it to false yet), so you play the sound (and try to reverse direction).

Try this:

```
-(void) stopWobbling {
    isWobbling = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        metronomeSlider.transform = vertical;
        [self stopMetronomeSound];
}]; }
```